# Why do we need to divide by 2! while considering the combinations in Enigma machine?

Tags: combinations

I would like to know why do we need to divide by 2! while considering pairs in p.11 of [Enigma Machine](https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/sjmiller/public_html/tas2012CrytpoBenford/unithandouts/unit2_chap_Enigma_SchrockMiller.pdf).The article says that:

"Number of ways to choose four letters from 26 letters is 
 $\frac {{26 \choose 4}{4 \choose 2}{2 \choose 2}}{2!}$"

but I can't get why do we need to divide by 2! since I think we're all have already done all the divisions to consider the combinations of the letters in the Enigma Machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\binom{24}{4}\binom 42\binom 22/2!$ counts selections of 4 from 24 letters (without replacement) into two pairs when we consider permutation *of the pairs* to be indistinct.

That is: we could select, for instance, ABCD, then divide them into pairs in three ways; which is $\binom 42/2!$ because, those pairings on the left column of the table are indistinct from those on the right of the same row. $$\begin{array}{c:c}AB,CD & CD, AB\\ \hdashline AC,BD & BD,AC\\ \hdashline AD, BC& BC, AD\\ \end{array}$$

Answer (score 0):

There are six ways to choose two out of four:
$$
\begin{array}{cc}
\text{chosen} & \text{unchosen} \\
AB & CD \\
AC & BD \\
AD & BC \\
BC & AD \\
BD & AC \\
CD & AB
\end{array}
$$
But if we're just interested in the number of ways to partition a set of four things into two subsets of two each, then choosing $AB$ and leaving $CD$ unchosen is the same as choosing $CD$ and leaving $AB$ unchosen. Likewise $AC$ versus $BD$ becomes the same thing as $BD$ versus $AC$, and $AD$ versus $BC$ becomes the same as $BC$ versus $AD$, so there are only half as many:
$$
\begin{array}{c} AB/CD \\ AC/BD \\ AD/BC \end{array}
$$